# Twilio no response from api server when messaging invalid number

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am testing some app code that is supposed to catch responses from messages sent to bad/invalid numbers on the Twilio API.   However, I am testing a bad number, a bad landline number, and I am not getting any response from the API.  But I have seen users fat finger their mobile number and the API response does provide a valid response; saying `undelivered` and typically with an error code.

Why isn't the server responding at all with the following bad landline number?

```
  $client = new Client($authID,$authSecret);
  $message = $client->messages->create(
      '+18135551212',
      array(
          'from' => $from,
          'body' => $msg
      )
  );
```

If I change to a valid mobile number then everything works.  But the purpose is to test various invalid/bad numbers or landline numbers in order to get the various responses.  But the above message gets no response from the server...there is no `$message`, hence there is no `$message->sid` to use in a webhook or status query.

Answer (score 0):

You can track delivery status updates using WebHooks: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery/php and https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/getting-started-twilio-webhooks

In your case, you need to specify a webhook in `create()`:

```php
$client = new Client($authID,$authSecret);
$message = $client->messages->create(
    '+18135551212',
    array(
        'from' => $from,
        'body' => $msg,
        'statusCallback' => "http://example.com/track"
    )
);

$message->sid // Store your message ID to identify it in your webook
```

Then, inside your page, you can receive and manage status updates (more details here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#twilios-request-to-the-statuscallback-url)

Status update is always asynchronous, that's why you need an "update listener" to understand if message was delivered correctly

Comment: This issue isn't about getting a status update on sent message.   This issue is about sending the message and the server doesn't respond at all.  Hence, there is no `$message->sid` to retrieve.

Comment: My post probably answer only your second (B) question, but i thought it was connected to the first one. Your example lacks quotes on the phone number, do you use quotes on your real code? Otherwise this will be interpreted as an integer @rolinger

Comment: i updated it, I manually wrote it versus copying from my working code.  In my real code I am not passing strings, I am passing a variable.  I just wrote it out so others could see the number I was using.